# How do I import 2 CSV files, compare values if one exists in another and produce a final CSV with a column stating if value exists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have 2 csv files with these columns

CSV 1

[image]

CSV 2

[image]

A desired output would be another CSV file with containing all columns from CSV1, and seeing if it exists in CSV2. An 'Exist' column will contain 1 if True and 0 if False.

[image]

Is there any way I could do this as efficiently as possible without using Pandas?

Comment: Have you tried pandas before? I think it's efficient to use pandas especially for data management like CSV file.

Comment: Yes I have and I solved this using a MERGE, but I am trying to challenge myself to solve this without Pandas. 

I know you can import CSV files using the "Import CSV" module in Python

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open CSV files without using Pandas or other packages, that is possible but it is not quite efficient. That's because you need to read and split based on the delimiter type manually. Here is the example:

Assuming you have list1.txt and list2.txt, respectively

```
name,email
red,red@gmail.com
blue,blue@gmail.com
```

```
name,email
green,green@gmail.com
red,red@gmail.com
```

Then, try to run the following script below

```py
file = open('list1.txt', 'r')
data1 = file.readlines()
for i in range(len(data1)):
    data1[i] = data1[i].rstrip().split(',')
file.close()

file = open('list2.txt', 'r')
data2 = file.readlines()
for i in range(len(data2)):
    data2[i] = data2[i].rstrip().split(',')
file.close()

for i in range(1,len(data1)):
    isexist = 0
    for j in range(len(data2)):
        if (data1[i][0] == data2[j][0]) and (data1[i][1] == data2[j][1]):
            isexist = 1
            print(data1[i][0], data1[i][1], isexist)
    if isexist == 0:
        print(data1[i][0], data1[i][1], isexist)
```

Finally, you have an output like below

```
red red@gmail.com 1
blue blue@gmail.com 0
```

Hopefully it helps your question.